# Get Array from Input Field Separated by Commas - Joomla 1.7

Tags: arrays, input, joomla

Using 1.7,

Right now I have this:

```
<input type="text" name="searchword" class="keyword_search_input" size="32" maxlength="255" value="<? echo JRequest::getString('searchword'); ?>" placeholder="<? echo JText::_('Keyword(s)'); ?>"/><br />
```

But I want to put the keywords separated by a space or comma into an array that will be passed to this:

```
$this->keywords = JRequest::getVar('searchword');

if ($keywords != "") $where_clause[] = ' s.keywords LIKE "%'.$keywords.'%"';

function getSearchword(){

        return $this->keywords;

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Nick

UPDATE:

I've figured this out. Thanks to @travega for pointing me in the right direction. Here is my input field:

```
<input type="text" name="searchword" class="keyword_search_input" size="32"    maxlength="255" value="<? echo JRequest::getString('searchword'); ?>" placeholder="<? echo JText::_('Keyword(s)'); ?>"/><br />
```

This passes a string to a construct function in my controller.php:

```
$this->keywords = JRequest::getVar('searchword');
```

This words in this string that are seperated by a comma and a space are then placed into an array by explode:

```
$this->keywords_array = explode(", ",$this->keywords);
```

This array of user inputed words is then compared to a MYSQL database of keywords:

```
if ($keywords != "") $where_clause[] = ' s.keywords LIKE "%'.$this->keywords_array[0].'%" OR s.keywords LIKE "%'.$this->keywords_array[1].'%"  ';
```

The only problem I have with this solution is that my search is limited to two values in keywords_array. I'd like to find a way to set the number of values in the search to equal to the number of values in the array...

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what format you "searchword" string will be in but if I understand correctly you wan to have multiple keywords to be built up in your "searchword" string and then passed back to you getSearchword() function.

For this you could use javaScript to append new search words to your string as they are added. Each time you add a sear term also add a comma to separate them. When you send your form your string will arrive like this:

```
hello,world,foo,bar
```

so you can use the explode() function in php to  turn it into an array of "searchwords"

```
$keywords_array = explode(",",$this->keywords);
```

Comment: Two questions: 1.Could you point me to a JS function to do this? 2. How could I modify the $where_clause to search for all the individual words in the array?

Comment: 1. Well it will depend on how your page works. But if your users enter a string say like "My name is bob" and submit the form then it will be easier to process the search string because you can just 'explode' the string on a blank space i.e. explode(" ", $keywords);. For this you won't need any JS to build your string. Otherwise if your user enters their keywords in multiple iterations then you can use jQuery to do: $("#foo").val(); to get the value where "foo" is the ID of your input element. Then look at adding the value to a hidden input field and (continued in next comment...)

Comment: 1.(contd...) use something like: $("#hiddenFoo").val($("#hiddenFoo").val() + "," +$("#foo").val()); to append the values to the hidden input field.

Comment: 2. Is it really necessary to store all of your word in an array? Is the list of keywords not likely to grow?? If so I'd advise using MySQL database lookups instead. If you do have to use static arrays then you will have to nest a where loop inside your loop through your keywords and for each value in your array of keywords you will have to iterate through every value in your search term array and check if they are equal. Definitely not a scalable solution but if they are your restraints for whatever reason then so be it.

Comment: Yes, you're right of course. The input keywords are not compared to an array of keywords but a database of keywords. Thanks.